# Serializing Array, reducing it, and serving just the name and value of the inputs in the array to ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form pushing to Zapier. I serialize the inputs into an array and then reduce it. Here's the code I use:

```
$(function() {
    $("#lead-gen-form").submit(function() {
        const formInputSerializedArray = $(this).serializeArray();
        const ajaxData = formInputSerializedArray.reduce((acc, { name, value }) => ({ ...acc, [name]: value }), {});
        $.ajax({
            url: "",
            type: "POST",
            data: { ajaxData },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                window.location = "../sent";
            },
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This results in this, which is including the name of the const and adding brackets around the name of the input, when all I really want to pull is the name of the input:

```
ajaxData[utm_campaign]: test
ajaxData[utm_term]: 12
ajaxData[utm_content]: comm
ajaxData[utm_medium]: email
ajaxData[utm_source]: sig
```

What I am looking to make it result in is:

```
utm_campaign: test
utm_term: 12
utm_content: comm
utm_medium: email
utm_source: sig
```

Comment: You're asking people to debug code they cannot run.  You really need to provide a [mre] so that people don't have to reconstruct your web page and your input data.  When people have to do that, there is a chance they will introduce errors themselves.  Your question should include the input, as well as a reproduction case for getting the actual output (i.e. runnable code).  That being said, try doing `data: ajaxData` insetead of `data: { ajaxData }`

Comment: @Tibrogargan That did it!!! Thanks so much. I didn't think providing the other code would be needed since I thought adding a replacement would be the solution to the variable to look for ajaxData and [ ] but I didn't know how to perform that within the replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When data is serialized by Ajax as JSON, it will include the name of the object being passed in so that it will create correctly formed JSON.  The anonymous object created by this `data: { ajaxData }` gets turned into `'{ "ajaxData": { "utm_campaign": ... } }'`

Simply remove the surrounding `{}` (use just `data: ajaxData`) and you will get the expected `'{ "utm_campaign": ... }'`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Very new to any programming like this, so I appreciate it a lot.